# Obtaining the pixel values of gray scale image from a binary image

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I do binary thresholding on a 16 bit gray scale image.This would help me in segmenting the region of interest.After binary thresholding,i would like to get the individual pixel intensities which are the intensities of the original 16 bit image and not the binary intensity values say 0,65535...

How can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

Find the region of interest in image segmentation using the binary image. After this, use the pixel locations in the 16 bit image for further processing of the image.

Answer (score 0):

To get a image from your original image, `I`  and a binary (logical) segmented image `BW`:

```
I2 = I.*BW;
```

`I2` should have the original values in the ROI and 0 elsewhere. Or, to get just a list of pixels and their values, via logical indexing:

```
I2 = I(BW);
```

Alternatively, depending on what you're doing, you may want to use `regionprops`:

```
stats = regionprops(BW,I,'MeanIntensity','PixelValues');
```

For a `BW` image showing the regions of interest, and a greyscale image `I` this will return the mean intensity and all list of all pixel values in `I` for each separate region (defined as a connected areas in `BW`).